# c++ argument of type x is incompatible with parameter of type with atexit

Tags: c++, std

I get this error when I try to run a function with theatexti() in std. I don't understand the error.

Here is the error:

```
 IntelliSense: argument of type "void (Demo3Main::*)()" is incompatible with parameter of type "void (__cdecl *)()"
```

and here is the code:

```
Demo3Main::Demo3Main(void)
: BaseEngine( 50 )
{
    atexit(RestorScore);
}

void Demo3Main::RestorScore(){
    std::ofstream outfile("old_score.txt");
    int num1 = 0;
    outfile << num1;
    outfile.close();
}
```

Comment: You are passing member function, but atexit expects free function?

Comment: hmmm im not sure what that means how could i solve this ?

Comment: You should probably save your data in the destructor, not as an exit handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ELI5 version**

The specifications for atexit's callback is

```
void (*function)(void)
```

This means you have to pass a function on the form:

```
void my_function()
{
}
```

But, you passed a class member function which has a different type. Its type is:

```
 void (Demo3Main::*)()
```

You can get your program to work by writing the function outside of a class. For example:

```
void RestorScore(){
   std::ofstream outfile("old_score.txt");
   int num1 = 0;
   outfile << num1;
}
atexit(RestoreScore);
```

Comment: Making the class member function `static` should work as well.

Comment: Good catch. I forgot about that. But, that will complicate the syntax for this simple case.